# PHP Converter for csv to .sav

Tags: spss

I Setup python Spss Converter but my Application on PHP
My First Question is how I call to Py function file in PHP lang?
Second, please give me some ideas on how to convert the CSV files to.SAV file on PHP?
I want to make Online Converter please help me